# AutoComplete AJAX Not Working

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, textbox, autocompleteextender

I am using an `AutoCompleteExtender` from AjaxControlToolkit on a `TextBox`.

To put it simply, when I drag and drop the `AutoCompleteExtender` tool on to my TextBox and then click on "Add AutoComplete page method", I get the following error:

> Cannot create page method "GetCompletionlist because no CodeBehind or
>   CodeFile was found!

After googling the error, I basically made my own web-service called AutoCompelte.asmx. Below is the code for that class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace AutoCompleteTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AutoComplete
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
        public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
            // Create array of movies  
            string[] movies = { "Star Wars", "Star Trek", "Superman", "Memento", "Shrek", "Shrek II" };

            // Return matching movies  
            return (from m in movies where m.StartsWith(prefixText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select m).Take(count).ToArray();
        }  
    }
}
```

Of course, the above is dummy data.... Later on, I shall be getting the data from a database.

And my Default.aspx looks like this:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    From
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>  


<asp:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" 
    ID="txtFrom_AutoCompleteExtender" 
    TargetControlID="txtFrom"
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
    ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
    MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
    CompletionInterval="1000"
    EnableCaching="true"
    CompletionSetCount="20"
    DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

When I run the website....and type in the textbox, nothing happens. No Extender is shown. Even if I type "Star".

What am I missing and why was I getting that error at the beginning?

P.S. I am on my University computers so, I think that error might be due to the type of network i am using. not sure.

Any help is HIGHLY HIGHLY HIGHLY appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: I got it working. I basically made a Website instead of a Website application. For some reason, that fixed the problem.

Comment: You really should post this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. This is how I fixed it:

My project was a "Website Application" in Visual Studio. When I simply made a "Website" project, it all worked perfectly.... I don't know why, it just did.

So if anyone else is having the same problem, try port the code over to a "Website" project rather than a "Website Application" project.

Hope that helps.